# "More results from" (same domain) on Bing

Tags: google-search, bing

On Google Search, if a search returns multiple results from the same site (e.g., forum sites, Super User...), you get a "More results from..." at the bottom to basically redo the original search with `site:domain` tacked on.

Is there a way to make Bing do this?